# how to find website domain controll panel with domain name?

Tags: web, web-hosting, forgot-password, controlpanel

Suppose, A web site owner lost the information regarding the site control panel information or from which company he buy the domain and so on....

this situation how to recover these information. ie- get domain control panel?

I have only the domain name.. `Ex:- the-boy.com.`

**Is there any way to find out the domain registered company/control panel by the domain name it self. ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use websites like [DomainTools](http://www.domaintools.com/) to see [WHOIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS) information:

```
Domain Name:     stackoverflow.com
Registrar:       Name.com LLC
```

Comment: i want know that, where he registered(like godady, domaincom), not who is registered.   thank you for replay...